# Help Translating Text Found On Oil Painting

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

Need help in translating this text found on an oil painting.  I believe it's medieval Latin but not sure if Christophorus and Lafranchini is the first and last name or two different people. Any help is appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 12):

There is such a name as [Christophorus Lafranchini](http://worldcat.org/identities/viaf-163153124300124490106/), though the years don't match, so they're not the same person.

*Pinxit* is the Latin for "painted," and *An~* here is likely *anno* meaning "in the year." So he painted it in 1778 at Verona.

Tripehound in the comments points out the *co* could be [an abbreviation](https://www.trismegistos.org/abb/detail.php?id=16912) for *coniugi*, which is the dative of *coniunx*, "spouse." However, on second glance there's a colon after *Co*, making that reading unlikely.

Edit: brianpck's answer has found the right person and solved the mystery of *co*.

Comment: Any ideas what "Co:" might mean?

Comment: Except... the book you refer to was published in 1584 if I read it right, so they cant be the same person

Comment: [This page](https://www.trismegistos.org/abb/detail.php?id=16912) lists potential meanings of "co", of which the most common is _coniugi_ which Google tells me means "spouse". If the subject of the painting is a woman, could it be the wife of Christophorus? Perhaps painted (by someone unknown) in 1778?

Comment: @TripeHound Presumably then you'd need the genitive *Christophori* to give 'wife of Christopher', though.

Comment: @Tripehound Good find. It's probably the dative instead. He painted it *for his wife*.

Comment: @anguscrossley Sorry if I was unclear. I meant it more that the name is attested, not that the two were the same person. I edited my post for clarity.

Answer (score 8):

I think I've found the figure in question: [Cristoforo Lafranchini](http://www.pastellists.com/Articles/Lafranchini.pdf#search=%22jeffares%22) is a pastellist with an article in Jeffares's *Dictionary of pastellists before 1800*. The linked entry says that he was active in Verona in 1773 (which corresponds well to the data and location in question) and--significantly--he has a title: Italian "conte"; Latin "comes"; English "count." In fact, the entire article seems to be based on the painting that the OP is asking about.

The full transcription is therefore:

> Co[mes] Christophorus Lafranchini pinxit an[no] 1773 Veronae

Translated:

> Count Cristoforo Lafranchini painted [me] in 1773 in Verona

Two other small changes:

- I am pretty sure the last number of the year is "3," not "8"
- It makes more grammatical sense for Verona to be in the locative, so I am assuming the loop under the "e" is intended to be a ligature for "ae," not just a flourish.

Comment: Good find! The book I saw didn't say he was a count, so that threw me off. I did see that he was noble though (one book says ["nobile Sig. Cristoforo Laffranchini"](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Istoria_della_Vita_e_delle_Opere_di_Raff/6SA6AAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22cristoforo+laffranchini%22&pg=PA329&printsec=frontcover), while someone below him was "sig. Conte").

Comment: Yes, you cracked it.

Answer (score -1):

It is meant to be read:

Collectione: Christoforus Lafranchini pinxit Anno 1779 Verona

Which means, "From the collection of Christopher Laffranchini, painted in the year 1779 at Verona"

FYI: "Co" in the context of art, refers to a collection or a collector, not to a wife. Laffranchini was an important art collector in Verona. There are dozens, if not hundreds of paintings that are provenanced from his collection throughout museums in Italy.

Comment: I guess I'd expect the genitive, *Christophori* and not *Christophorus*. Also, what is the subject of *pinxit* if not *Christophorus*?

Comment: @Figulus Laffranchini was a collector, not a painter. Maybe it would have been more grammatically correct to write "pictus est" or something like that, but you have to remember we are talking about very casual Latin here.

Comment: @TylerDurden Do you have sources for that? I couldn't find anything with an admittedly rudimentary Google search.

Comment: @TylerDurden What do you mean by this being very casual? Isn't a painting an expensive item with which one might want to be careful? I wouldn't dismiss such a discrepancy between the original and your translation so quickly.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta Look, if you want to believe that Laffranchini painted it for his wife, fine. I am just telling you that is totally wrong.

Comment: @TylerDurden I have no strong opinion. It's just that if you are telling that something is totally correct and something else is totally wrong, I would expect a stronger argument. If you can add some reasoning to your answer for why it has to be that way, that'd be great.

Comment: @TylerDurden, can you provide a name of one of those dozens of paintings in his collocation? I seem to be unable to find any information about this.

Comment: I didn't ask for a source because I think you're wrong, I asked for a source because, like @d_e, I cannot find anything about this online. A search on the name comes up empty. Can you point to a museum page, a book, some source from which we can gather more information?

Comment: @cmw "Atti e memorie dell'Accademia di Agricoltura Scienze e Lettere di Verona" v172 p. 417. "Istoria della vita e delle opere di Raffaello Sanzio de Urbino," p. 329. "Le fanciulle celebri e l'infanzia delle donne illustri d'Italia antiche e Moderne" p. 269.

Comment: @d_e "La Fornarina" (possibly) by Raphael which now hangs in the Borghese gallery originally came from the Laffranchini collection. That's one painting.

Comment: @TylerDurden Grazie molte.

Comment: I'm downvoting, not because I don't think "co." means "collectio[ne]" (in fact, that seems more probable than *coniugi*), but because "Christoforus" is clearly the grammatical subject of *pinxit*. The provided translation simply ignores the nominative.

Comment: @brianpck, just was about to write something similar. despite the reference given, I still believe Christopher Laffranchini was the painter. In one reference I saw a ref of "heir of Laffranchini from 1829" also he was operating in Verona. I find it more probable that  Laffranchini painted this in 1779 Verona. It is hard to find information about this man online; it might be he was a collector indeed (in which case his collected works were painted much earlier than 1772 Verona); + it is what written *pinixt* it is a known formula.  why would C.L use this formula *on* a painting not his?